# How to define an infinite range of a generic integer type in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a generic type `T` that implements the `num::Integer` trait. I can write a `T`-based range iterator where `e` represents another value of type `T` denoting the upper bound of the range:

```
num::iter::range(T::one(), e)
```

The annoying thing is that it is necessarily bounded. How can I have an unbounded range? For primitive types, I can do something like `(1..)`. Can I do something like `num::iter::range(T::one(), T::infinity())`?

I can't find a function that does this in `num::iter`. I would like to be able to call functional style functions afterwards like `map`, `filter` etc...

Comment: Most integer types (e.g. `u8`, `i32`) cannot represent the concept of "infinity". Iterators like `(0u8..)` will panic (debug mode) or wrap (release mode). What are you actually attempting to solve?

Comment: You could use https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Bounded.html, T::max_value. But I also don't see the point.

Comment: Say I wanted to have some functional code on T and use ```take_while_ref``` from ```itertools``` to specify a custom terminating condition that may be complicated, and for which I could not/would be lazy to estimate an upper bound, and say T is not bounded like BigInt. Could I do it?

Comment: I do not have a particular goal with this except trying to write beautiful code. I am imagining possible situations. If take_while_ref already specifies a stopping criterion it feels ugly to add an upper bound just because i don't know how not to specify it.

Comment: Have you solved this somehow?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Edit:** Unfortunately, `std::ops::RangeFrom` is a struct, not a trait like for example the traits for infix operators in `std::ops`. So this is wrong, but since it has been accepted I can't delete it.

**Original post**: You can implement [std::ops::RangeFrom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html) for your type.  This is the trait underlying the range syntax with only a lower bound, like e.g. `1..`.

Comment: Yes thats my conclusion also. For some reason num::BigInt does not seem to have any Range implemented and num::iter lacks RangeFrom

Comment: `RangeFrom` is not a trait. The underlying trait behind all ranges is [`Step`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Step.html), which is not stable yet.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a use case for `loop`, not a range.

Comment: I want to constrain myself to go with functional programming style, and use ```map```, ```fold```, ```filter``` kind of things, I think you are talking about imperative style loops. Am i wrong? If we are always supposed to do imperative and use loop, then my question becomes why does ```take_while_ref``` exist?